Not booting into windows and going into grub
I was trying to dual-boot Ubuntu and partitioned 40 GB (I think I labeled it as U drive) for it in Windows. Afterward, I tried installing Ubuntu 22.04.05 LTS on my Fujitsu Lifebook E series. I think I formatted it as ext2 and took 2 GB from my 40 GB for EFI (no idea what that means; I just did it because the installation prompt told me I needed it). I started the installation and got an error message: GRUB couldn't be installed, fatal error, or something like that. I then followed a tutorial where I downloaded and ran an application called Boot Repair (in "Try Ubuntu"). After it finished, it said that it was successful. I restarted my laptop (pushed and held the power button) and, after powering it on again, it went into something called GRUB. I followed another tutorial where somebody said this worked for them. GRUB> Is GRUB> Is (hd0,gpt3)/ //in my case (hd0,msdos9) grub> set root=(hd0,gpt3) grub> configfile /boot/grub/ grub.cfg It should have gone into Ubuntu, but I was still GRUB. And now I can't boot into Windows (I tried every option in the boot menu). What can I do? In the worst case, I would like to boot into Windows (I have important files there) and reformat the 40 GB partition I made for Ubuntu

It would be useful to post the boot-repair report link in your original posting -- we don't really have enough information to make useful suggestions. We cannot even tell if you have a legacy install of windows or a UEFI install.

You could use the live-USB to fix the partitions. Choose 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.. Open Gparted and delete the 40gb partition and the 2gb partition. At this point it's advisable to connect to the internet if possible. Then click on the icon to 'Install Ubuntu 22.04' and choose 'Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows' when prompted. Ubuntu will be installed in the 42gb of freespace/unallocated. That should fix your boot issue. Or you can run the 'Boot Repair' app instead of installing Ubuntu. When you're done you need to power off the PC from the panel/desktop. Don't hold down the power button. During shutdown you'll be prompted to "remove the install medium, and press enter" Then power up normally.  .....Or you could install the Live GParted .ISO (https://gparted.org/livecd.php) to a USB and use that to delete the partitions. You would still need to repair the GRUB. Following these steps is likely faster than trying method after method to no avail.
